# Having PHP code in one page rather than two

Tags: php, html

I have a number of registration pages on my web application and a number of textboxes in a form that pushes the values enter to another php page which writes it to the database. The code for it looks like this

```html
<form action = "submitEvent.php" method = "post"> 
  Event Name: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventname" > 
  <br>
  Event Type: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventtype" > 
  <br>
  Charity Number: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "charityid" > 
  <br>
  Contact Details: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "contactdetails" > 
  <br>
  Location: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventlocation" > 
  <br>
  Date : <br>
  <input type ="date" name ="eventdate">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
</form>
```

and then the submitEvent.php file looks like this

```html
<?php
$eventname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventname');
$eventtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventtype');
$charitynumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'charityid');
$contactdetails = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contactdetails');
$eventlocation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventlocation');
$eventdate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventdate');
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fyp";

//Create new connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "INSERT
    INTO event (eventname, eventtype, charityid, contactdetails, location, date) VALUES ('$eventname', '$eventtype', '$charitynumber', '$contactdetails', '$eventlocation', '$eventdate')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "New record created succesfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  ?>
```

Is there an easier way to do this as I have a number of pages like this? Would I be able to put it into one page?

Comment: yes, it's perfectly possible to have it all in one page. You just need to check, before you execute the PHP which handles the insertion, that the current request is indeed the one where the form was posted. You can just check that the request is using the POST method to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have all this in one page. You can use isset($_POST) to check if there is data available and then process it.
But modulation (having separate files) makes it easy. It helps to debug when you have php and html codes in diff files.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the form is submitted or not and act accordingly.

To check if you the form is submitted you can check if `$_POST['Submit']` is set.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
  /* PHP code here */
}

?>
<!-- And point the form to submit to itself. -->

<form action="thisPage.php" method="post"> 
<!-- Rest of form here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way is add a hidden field to your form and on the form page check for that in php.

**HTML**

```
<form action = "form_page.php" method = "post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
.....
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submitted"])){

/*PHP processing code goes here*/

}
?>
```